# SegWit address to Non-SegWit addresses

Tags: segregated-witness

If I send from a segwit wallet to a non segwit wallet, does the tx not show up in the other wallet until there is a confirmation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not about the type of address but wallet. Some will show unconfirmed balances/transactions, others won't.

Comment: What is it about?